# Почему текст повторяется на странице?

Tags: java, android

У меня такая проблема. Есть страница подтверждения номера телефона через firebase.
На странице подтверждения номера где нужно вводить код, есть повторяющийся текст.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код SendActivity

```
public class SendOTPActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_o_t_p);

        final EditText inputMobile = findViewById(R.id.inputMobile);
        Button buttonGetOTP = findViewById(R.id.buttonGetOTP);

        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        buttonGetOTP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(inputMobile.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(SendOTPActivity.this, "Enter Mobile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonGetOTP.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        "+7" + inputMobile.getText().toString(),
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        SendOTPActivity.this,
                        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                buttonGetOTP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                buttonGetOTP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(SendOTPActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                buttonGetOTP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerifyOTPActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("mobile", inputMobile.getText().toString());
                                intent.putExtra("verificationId", verificationId);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                );

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Код VerifyActivity

```
public class VerifyOTPActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputCode1, inputCode2, inputCode3, inputCode4, inputCode5, inputCode6;
    private String verificationId;

    private static String global_url = AppConst.Server_url;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_o_t_p);

        context = VerifyOTPActivity.this;

        TextView textMobile = findViewById(R.id.textMobile);
        textMobile.setText(String.format(
                "+7" + getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile")
        ));

        inputCode1 = findViewById(R.id.inputCode1);
        inputCode2 = findViewById(R.id.inputCode2);
        inputCode3 = findViewById(R.id.inputCode3);
        inputCode4 = findViewById(R.id.inputCode4);
        inputCode5 = findViewById(R.id.inputCode5);
        inputCode6 = findViewById(R.id.inputCode6);

        setupOTPInputs();

        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final Button buttonVerify = findViewById(R.id.buttonVerify);

        verificationId = getIntent().getStringExtra("verificationId");

        buttonVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(inputCode1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
                        ||inputCode2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
                        ||inputCode3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
                        ||inputCode4.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
                        ||inputCode5.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
                        ||inputCode6.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(VerifyOTPActivity.this, "Please enter valid code!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                String code = inputCode1.getText().toString() +
                        inputCode2.getText().toString() +
                        inputCode3.getText().toString() +
                        inputCode4.getText().toString() +
                        inputCode5.getText().toString() +
                        inputCode6.getText().toString();

                if(verificationId != null){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonVerify.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                            verificationId,
                            code
                    );
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    buttonVerify.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SubscribeActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("account_type","customer");
                                        intent.putExtra("mobile", textMobile.getText().toString());
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    } else{
                                        Toast.makeText(VerifyOTPActivity.this, "The verification code entered was invalid!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.textResendOTP).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        "+7" + getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile"),
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        VerifyOTPActivity.this,
                        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(VerifyOTPActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String newVerificationId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                verificationId = newVerificationId;
                                Toast.makeText(VerifyOTPActivity.this, "OTP sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });

    }

    private void setupOTPInputs(){
        inputCode1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputCode2.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        inputCode2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputCode3.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        inputCode3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputCode4.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        inputCode4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputCode5.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        inputCode5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputCode6.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Код это, конечно, хорошо. Но как вы предлагает разбираться в этой куче кода ничего не зная? Как, например, называется строка, в которой этот текст? И как выглядит разметка. Проблема наверняка в ней

Answer (score 1):

1. У Вас текст расположен под кнопкой на обоих скринах, просто на втором - кнопка ушла в INVISIBLE состояние. Когда показывается кнопку - скрывайте вью с текстом под ней.
2. Не называйте вьюхи inputCode1, невозможно ж разобрать что внутри этих вью
3. Как без xml то помогать, в вопросе оч мало инфы для помощи..